# Let X and Y be random variables with finite means. Does E[Y*E[Y|X]] = E[Y]E[Y]?

Tags: statistics

I'm working on a problem where I believe I eventually need to show that E[Y * E[Y|X]] = E[Y]E[Y]. Is this true? The obvious way to prove it would be to show that Y and E[Y|X] are independent, but I haven't been able to do so.  When I use the covariance formula I get an expression involving E[Y * E[Y|X], which doesn't help me.

Answer (score 2):

No, it's not true.   Consider the case $X=Y$.  Then $E[Y|Y] = Y$, so 
$E[Y E[Y|X]] = E[Y^2]$.  This is not the same as $E[Y]^2$.

In fact, by the Law of total expectation and the fact that $E[Y|X]$ is a function of $X$, 
$$E[Y E[Y|X]] = E[E[Y E[Y|X] | X]] = E[E[Y|X]^2] $$

Comment: $E[Y|Y]=Y$ or $E[Y]$?

Comment: $E[Y|Y] = Y$, and more generally $E[f(Y)|Y]=f(Y)$.

Answer (score 1):

It is not true, but if $X$ and $Y$ are independent, then $\mathsf{E}[Y|X]=\mathsf{E}[Y]$, and $\mathsf{E}[Y\mathsf{E}[Y|X]]=\mathsf{E}[Y\mathsf{E}[Y]]=\mathsf{E}[Y]\mathsf{E}[Y]$.